# How do I back up my files from my admin account with logging in?

Tags: 14.04, server

I cannot access my administrative account and I am using Ubuntu version 14.04. So far I am using the guest session account. Is there a way I could copy a file from my administrative account and paste it with my guest session?

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot access my administrative account

It would be advisable to always include -why- you can not. You are now asking for a solution to a question you might not want or does not have you end up with a method where you can use it.

---

In general you can switch users on command line with

```
 su - {user}
```

(mind the `-`). and when asked provide the password for the admin. Thing is: if the reason you can not use the admin account because you do not know the password this will not be of any help to you.

---

If that is the case you should reboot the server and at the grub prompt go to a system prompt and change the admin password. See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/15811) from Jorge Castro for an example on how to do this.

Comment: I already did the suggestion. But when i hit enter and the system ask for my password. The answer would always be command not found.